# Add delegate to custom UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, delegates

I have a custom `UITableView` integrated in my `ViewController`, with more elements, and I tried to add to the `UITableView` a control to refresh its content, like twitter app. The problem is that I can't capture the scrolls of the tableview in the ViewController. If I set the `delegate` of the custom `UITableView`, then I can capture the scrolls but I get troubles with the custom table behavior. 
So, I don't know what it's better, either find the way to add the delegate for scrolls without override anything or find a way to add the control to refresh the table from the ViewController, not from the UITableView class.

The case with more details is:

- A library for the custom UITableView. It's used to draw a conversation like the message app. So I just pass the information to the table and the table draw it. I don't do anything more, not delegate, nothing, just add the table to my ViewController.
- I put the methods of the scroll's delegate in my ViewController, and, when I do scroll in the table, I don't get anything(the app doesn't enter in the scroll's delegate methods). If I set the table's delegate to self, the scroll works but I get some random problems from the table( I don't know how it's made the table), so I have to discard this option(set the delegate).

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of trouble do you get when setting the delegate?

Comment: The tableviews is like the messages app. The troubles is that the messages with more than 2 lines don't appear correctly, sometimes one above another, for example

Comment: What class are you using for the pull-to-refresh control? Usually they work just by assigning them to the scroll view. They internally observe `contentOffset` property.

Comment: Yes. I got a library from the Internet, and in other viewcontrollers it works fine(when the viewcontroller is a uitableviewcontroller), but in this one(normal viewcontroller), it doesn't work because the scrolls that the control recognize are from the viewcontroller, not from the uitable

Comment: You will need to expand the question with some details and code. Do you have multiple scroll views there? How can the control recognize scrolling of view controller?

Comment: Are you doing all updates in the main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the UIRefreshControl object. You define this object in the viewController in the viewDidLoad method and add the target to your tableView when it's value changes, here is an example:

```
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self.tableView action:@selector(reloadData) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Your viewController needs to be a UITableViewController however. To initiate and end the refresh use the methods:

```
[self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
[self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
```